# Populating a dropdownlist from a database troubles

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I am trying to pre-populate a DropDownList as the page loads. I am getting an error when I run that the keyword DataSource is not supported, and the line of code that is highlighted is where I declare the variable con - As New SqlConnection(CS). in the LoadList procedure. The Exact error **:An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'datasource'.**

I am very confused by this, and haven't been able to find that great of documentation on the issue. Here is my web.config markup, followed by the code behind for aspx.vb page. 
Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you !

Web Config:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="GoForGold" connectionString="datasource=local;database=Friends;integrated     security=SSPI"/>   
</connectionStrings>
```

aspx.vb:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.Control
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    DropDownList1.Items.Clear()
    DropDownList1.Items.Add("Please Select")
    DropDownList1.AppendDataBoundItems = True
    If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
        LoadList()
    End If
End Sub


Protected Sub LoadList()
    Dim CS As    String=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("GoForGold").ConnectionString                                 
    Dim Query As String = "SELECT * FROM Name"
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(CS)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = Query
    cmd.Connection = con

    Try
        con.Open()
        DropDownList1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "First_Name"
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Friend_ID"
        DropDownList1.DataBind()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it needs to be two words, also to access a DB on the local host it should say 'localhost' instead of 'local':

```
<add name="GoForGold" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Database=Friends;Integrated Security=SSPI"/>
```

Comment: Just tried that now its is saying the following error..(maybe i need  help with naming instead)     **An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in App_Web_4wo4ok12.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)**

Comment: Wait, you should also have 'localhost' instead of 'local'

Comment: In that case, could you make sure to mark my answer as accepted so I can get the points? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your connection is for Oracle, which uses `Datasource`

Sql Server connection string looks like this

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

For Windows Authentication use as follows:

```
 Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI
```

Or

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=Yes
```

Comment: If i use windows authentication, can I exclude the user id, and password and just have server address and database? Also, would server address just be my ip adress?

Comment: Server is ip or the server name. With win auth, try not set id/password. You will need t add `Trusted_Connection=Yes`, I think